# Use of subject again after "and" is more natural or not?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Example: 
"**I** like reading books and love to swim"
or 
"**I** like reading books and **I** love to swim"

Comment: The sentence is lacking *paralellism*. Since you use *gerund* at the first clause, you must use gerund for the second clause too. *love swimming*. Idk much about a sentence idiomaticality, but I would omit *I* after *and*

Comment: Omitting the subject "I" in the second coordinate is okay, but I'd be inclined to retain it..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Both are natural.

Long answer: Repeating the subject usually means there is something you want to emphasize.

For example, "I like reading *and* I love to swim,"

> ...lets the listener feel like you are a person of many interests and hobbies,

...whereas "I like reading and I *love* to swim,"

> ...lets the listener know that you have these two hobbies, but you care for the latter more passionately.

Does this help?

Comment: you wrote the same sentences

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are grammatical and idiomatic. In short clauses, omitting repetitions of the subject leads to a clause that is both concise and easily understood. However, in lengthy clauses, where verbs are separated by one or more phrases or subordinate clauses, omitting repetitions of the subject may lead to a clause that is very hard to interpret. So, as general rule of style that undoubtedly has exceptions, I'd tend to omit repeatitions of the subject for verbs that are close together, but repeat the subject for verbs that are separated by multiple phrases or any subordinate clause.